# How to automate the running of Jupyter notebooks one after another?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a few jupyter notebooks and I want to run them one after another and each one of them takes a lot of time to complete.

What I have been able to think of so far is to put all the code in one notebook, which I  don't want to do, another is to run the next notebook via command executed in the present notebook, but don't know  how to do that either

What are the possible ways to do so ?
All the help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the optimal solution. But may solve your problem.

Try to run this way in the command line.

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to sample_notebook1.ipynb --inplace sample_notebook1.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to sample_notebook2.ipynb --inplace sample_notebook2.ipynb
```

You would not be able to see the results during the execution. But once a notebook is ran, you should be able to see the output inside the notebook.

Note: Add extra enter at the end of the final line. Or else your last notebook would be waiting for your enter to execute.

Comment: Supposedly you can use papermill to check results while the other cells in the notebook are waiting to run as it saves the results of each cell as it runs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663213/make-jupyter-nbconvert-write-output-to-notebook-after-each-cell-finishes-instead). I haven't used that feature and so I cannot confirm that ability.